# How do I import a C-function to Ada with pass-by-reference arguments?

Tags: ada

I have a C function `int func( int a, int* b)` that I need to import and use in Ada 95. Where the C function would typically be called in C as `c = func(a, &b);`

I import C functions all the time into Ada, but have always avoided using functions with pass by reference arguments, but it's finally time to learn.

I would like to know how to declare this function in Ada, and would also like a quick example of using it with declared variables shown (because I'm still a little fuzzy on the Access types).

Thanks all!

Comment: C does not have references. That's why you have to use pointers. They are passed by value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, `int* b` can mean a lot of things. Perhaps it's really just a pointer to one variable, but it may also be an array for which `int a` is the length. This code assumes that `int* b` is actually just a value that's passed by reference:

```
with Interfaces.C;

-- ...
package C renames Interfaces.C;

function Func (A : C.int; B : access C.int) return C.int;
pragma Import (Convention => C, Entity => Func,
               External_Name => "func");

-- ...

declare
   A : C.int := 42;
   B : aliased C.int := 23;
   C : C.int;
begin
   C := Func (A, B'Access);
   -- ...
end;
```

You can use `'Access` on `aliased` variables. This is safe as long as you're sure that the pointer won't be stored on the C side and accessed after the end of life of variable `B`. (If the C declaration uses the `const` keyword, you can use `access constant` on the Ada side, but that's Ada 2005 only.)

You can also use a named type:

```
-- ...
type Int_Access is access C.int;
function Func (A : C.int; B : Int_Access) return C.int;
-- ...
C := Func (A, B'Unchecked_Access);
-- ...
```

Now we need to use `'Unchecked_Access` because Ada normally does not allow a non-local access type (as `Int_Access`) to refer to a local variable. If you know what the C code will do with the pointer (like you should), you can use named types to specify that no references to local variables should be passed.

**Nota bene 1:** If you have a procedure (in C: a function that returns `void`), you can specify a variable to be passed by reference by using `in out` in your Ada procedure declaration instead of `access`. This way, you do not need to worry about access types at all. As before, you need to be sure that the pointer is not stored at the C side.

**Nota bene 2:** Record types and arrays are passed by reference anyway - unless you specify `pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, Your_Type);`. This is a common gotcha when wrapping C functions in Ada.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, this also clears up some other questions I had about how things worked between Ada and C.

Comment: Passing records by reference for C-interface functions always annoyed me; C structs, like all C types, are passed by copy. It would have made more sense to pass them by copy by default, and pass a pointer explicitly if the C function takes a pointer to a struct.

Comment: And I'm fairly sure `C_Pass_By_Value` is specific to GNAT (though I wouldn't surprised if other Ada compilers have adopted it).

Comment: I got the name wrong. The correct name of the pragma is `C_Pass_By_Copy`, and it is indeed a GNAT-specific pragma in Ada 95. It has been added to Ada 2005.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to (and plagiarizing from flyx) I offer a full solution:

File c_thing.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (int a, int * b) {
  printf ("A:%d, B %d\n",a, *b);
}
```

File ada_main.adb

```
with Interfaces.C;

procedure Ada_Main is 

   package C renames Interfaces.C;

   function Func (A : C.int; B : access C.int) return C.int;
   pragma Import (Convention => C, Entity => Func,
                  External_Name => "foo");

   A : C.int := 42;
   B : aliased C.int := 23;
   R : C.int;

begin

   R := Func (A, B'Access);

end Ada_Main;
```

To Compile (linux):

```
gcc -c c_thing.c
gnatmake -c ada_main.adb
gnatbind ada_main.ali
gnatlink ada_main.ali c_thing.o
```

To Run

```
./ada_main 
A:42, B 23
```